# A variation on the Markov Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

A vague question. I need to study the triples of integers which solve the Diophantine equation $x^2-y^2-z^2=xyz$. I know little about Diophantine equations in general, so I would like to know if this equation has ever been studied in detail and/or what can be said about its solutions.

Comment: Yes, $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=dxyz$ has been studied in general. For references (Rosenberger, and Kern-Isberner), see, say, [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03322067), or search for further posts.

Comment: the first extension was by Hurwitz, it is in German but still pretty easy, http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  Your version keeps one thing, we may jump from solution to neighbors using Vieta Jumping, flipping one variable at a time. The down side is that you need to allow the variables negative sometimes. Oh, the version $x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = d xyz$  keeps the integer jumping..  The big question is whether  we may travel from any solution back to $(-1,-1,-1)$

Comment: meanwhile, vieta jumping does not change $\gcd(x,y,z) ,$   so the points connected with $(-1,-1,-1)$  all have $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$

Comment: appears  we must add a complication, at any stage we may negate two  of $x,y,z$  and keep the third where it is. Otherwise I don't see how to force $|x| +|y|+|z|$ to shrink

Comment: Thank you both! This was very helpful.